# Export BGE Soft-body Distortions to 3D view?

Tags: game-engine, physics, soft-body

Is it possible to get BGE soft-body simulations into the normal viewport? I know you can get the animation of the object itself, (with record animation to keyframes) but how to get the distortions of the softbody?

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear to be possible.  You'd probably have to write a script to export it, but:
"There are no python bindings to control soft bodies, and no logic brick support, except for apply force and add object actuator. " - http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/GameEngine/BulletSoftBody

(I can't yet reply to your question to clarify.  What are you trying to accomplish?  You have another question about multiple soft bodies colliding, is the problem related? like I said, combining them into one object works, but a drawback is they have to all have the same settings... but with more detail to your problem, there may be a way.)

Comment: don't worry about his other question at the moment. Just try to answer this one :)

Comment: I answered this one and his other one.

It stinks not being able to reply to questions/answer for clarifications yet.  So I put it in parenthesis.  I'm trying to solve his problem, which appears to have manifested as this question.

My questions:  Why try to export BGE's soft body as a regular animation?  What is wrong with the regular softbody modifier, that is more powerful?  

I'm guessing it has to do with colliding softbody objects, which I told him how to do in the other question, but I don't know.)

Comment: it's true that the built in simulator is more powerful than the game engine. However, it would be easier to create an animation if you could easily interact with the simulation itself (I think that's the main reason he would use it instead).

Comment: Good idea, perhaps he wants to interact with it.  (That's somewhat possible with the regular one too.  Run the sim a few frames, modify the interacting object's animation, and repeat,  But yes, not as easily.)  A little background on what he's trying to do, that's inspiring these questions would make better use of our energy.  I realize the place for me to write these questions is on his question, but I can't yet.  I think I need just one more upvote.

Comment: @CharlesL The main reason I want to use the BGE softbody is partly so I can have rigid-body to soft body as well as soft body to soft body collisions, it is also faster (obviously) yet looks passable. (IMO)