# Is there any way to export soft body simulation to Unity?

Tags: animation, export, unity, shape-keys, soft-body

I have a mesh with soft body simulation. Is there any way to export it to Unity?

So far I have baked the simulation into shape keys, and created key frames for shape keys values in every frame, using this script: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35564/13487
But I can't import it into Unity - I see my object freezed, or invisible at all.

I would be super gratefull for help in finding a solution!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I had the same problem. Try to export .fbx file manually from Blender and import to Unity as described in one of the answers here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101935/cloth-simulation-for-game-engine-doesnt-get-animated-despite-shape-keys-have-be