# How to speed up blender animation playback. It is slow

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I've been trying to make this animation, and every where I've looked people don't have as low of fps.

I have a 16GB RAM computer with a new graphics card.
(I'm able to play Mine craft and blow up a TNT town with Little lag)
( And I'm able to play counter strike at a constant 90 fps )

Example:
[image: slow animation play back]

Comment: When playing an animation, 2 fps is pretty good. I get as low as .05 with complex meshes and a lot of objects. I think this is normal.

Comment: Be sure to [bake](http://blender.org/manual/physics/baking.html) any physics simulations

Comment: You could also upload the file for others to compare fps or spot something that is slowing down your animation. Sometimes you can do things in different ways, and you could get unnecessary slowness. But if you have doubts about your pc, try a "standard" blender benchmark, and compare your times with others (although ususally benchmarks are mainly for evaluate rendering times), see some of those here http://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/

Comment: Delete all the unnecessary or all the keyframes in the anim player and add new ones.

Answer (score 6):

Actually your GPU will have a little impact on your view-port fps when playing animation. If you are able to rotate/navigate without lag, your GPU can handle the geometry fine (almost any modern GPU will handle millions of polys). Then if you get slow fps in playback the bottleneck is somewhere else.

If you get lag in just navigating view port check the OpenGL settings in *User Preferences* under *System* tab. Enable VBO.

Between each frame, the scene has to be updated with all the objects inside - this happens on CPU. Behind the scene this is managed by [Dependency graph](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.75/Animation#Dependency_Graph) - a structure that keeps track what is dependent on what (parenting, constraints, ..). The current dependency graph is obsolete and is single threaded in many places = does not use all the CPU power, has poor optimization = is re-evaluated in cases where it is not needed, etc.

You can try the new *DepsGraph* with a command line argument (see the link above).

Things to do to help your animation fps (if anyone has other tricks or I forgot some feel free to expand the list):

- If there are simulations/particles always bake or at least cache them so they don't need to be recalculated between frames.
- If there are deformations on subdivided geometry use *Simplify* in Scene properties to limit the subdivisions - less vertices have to be updated. Or try the [OpenSubdiv](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/OpenSubdiv) option to calculate it on GPU (but this still has limitations)
- Close any other view-port windows - have just one. Set it to *Only Render* in the Display settings in Properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>). If you have animated textures close also Image/UV windows.
- If your deformed geometry doesn't change vertex order/count you can export it as .mdd file format and import back in Blender or [bake it into Shape Keys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23566/7777).
- There is not much else you can do, if nothing works the scene is just too complex and your only option is to preview the animation with OpenGL preview render (button in view-port header)

Comment: I think there's something else at play here.  If I scrub by hand everything plays back as fast as I scrub it.  It's only slow if I use alt a or press play....not sure why that would be?

Answer (score 3):

for me - and i dont even have GPU)*-  the following things speeded the viewport performance during aninmation incredibly up:

- evee render / fps 30 / solid view
- Render Settings / Simplify / Viewport / Max. Subdivision -> set to "0"
- hide applied booleans, or modifiers like wirefrime from viewport visibilty (uncheck viewportdisplay checkbox in modifiers panel)

Happy blender :-) @synhaptix
P.S. * Mac ox 10.14 / 4.2 ghz, intel Core i7 / 32 GB Ram / Radeon Pro 580 8192 MB

Edit: corrected 60 fps to 30 fps

Comment: sorry -little correction - 30 fps

Comment: Render Settings > Simplify took me from 5 to 30 FPS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go into the *Object* tab under *Visibility* and toggle off *Viewports* for both objects.