# Where should I go for Blender questions about 3d adult videos?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

(If this is a problem, I will delete it.)

I'm making 3d adult videos as a blender as a hobby.

When I learn one by one, I get two or three questions every time.

If I post the question here now, it seems to be against the regulations, 
so I just upload the question.

Can not I post Blender questions about adult video here?

Or where can I ask this question?

Comment: Hey! I recommend joining one of the 2 major blender discord (chat application) servers, both of which have optionally restricted NSFW room for questions and showcase.

Comment: You can also try to generalise your questions and not for example ask for exact body part but instead find another similar real world behaviour. Also I think this is a good topic for meta.

Comment: Thank you. I know discord, but I do not know exactly where to post questions about NSFW. Could you tell me more details?

Comment: You can still ask here if you generalize the question about modeling, rigging texturing,etc. If you need to show images just make it so that they are not offensive to minors  or other users, or use other objects to illustrate your point. As always if you are looking for critique and opinions or subjective criteria this is not the place. You can read through the [help] section to understand how the site works, and read also this post on off-topic questions: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Comment: There are nsfw places where you can ask uncensored, but you won't reach as big community. You cannot post adult content here, because people in work and kids use this site. What you can do is to think about an example that accomplishes what you want, but is innocent. Take this question as an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112410/how-to-do-a-transformation-deformation (see edits of it how it looked originally)