# Soft body to keyframes script crash

Tags: scripting, soft-body

i am trying to use the script from another [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-to-bake-softbody-animation-into-keyframes). It works as it says, The problem is when i try to render the blender crashes. The frames are about 100. I have about 1200 frames of soft body simulation and i want in the last 100 frames to control better the animation.I think the script is perfect.But i do not know if there are to many frames to convert in shape keys or maybe the shaders.

I have a scene with some thing like an inflate mass that transforms after 1200 frames. I have made a falling and rolling simulation, but I want this inflate mass to be in complete rest position.But because of the movement momentum, this isn't happened inside the simulation, it's keeps somehow moving,and I cannot animate the mesh like the simulation, to make it look like resting.So I was thinking to keyframe the last 100 frames, scale them, so it is like it stopped

Comment: Assuming you have used [script in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23566/15543).  How big is the mesh (vert / poly count), run from console look for error messages, look in tmp folder for `blender.crash.txt` text file and post here.  A workaround would be to split into smaller files.  Say 12 100 frame files.  Would be 1100 less shape keys in each file.

Comment: I try to avoid that because it will be a workflow mess

Comment: Have you tried the mdd cache suggested in answer?  To have a workflow that leads to monstrous blend files that crash your machine... you might want to invest in hardware.

Comment: My hardware is good i think, 16gb ram gtx 1080 ti and intel i7 7800x.It is not the machine that crashes, but the blender.I think that mdd doesnt work in my situation. I have a soft body and make it look like rest-stops, the concept was to keyframe it and scale the keyframes

Comment: lol meant crash blender.  Haven't used mdd myself, in theory tho I thought you could edit the cache. Isn't it just like caching the shapekey mesh to disk.. if so surely you can edit it.  Could you elaborate on how last 100 frames will control first 1100? (edit into question rather than comment)

Comment: I have a scene with some thing like an inflate mass that transforms after 1200 frames. I have made a falling and rolling simulation, but I want this inflate mass to be in complete rest position.But because of the movement momentum, this isn't happened inside the simulation, it's keeps somehow moving,and I cannot animate the mesh like the simulation, to make it look like resting.So I was thinking to keyframe the last 100 frames, scale them, so it is like it stopped.