# How can I move this soft body and empty to another project after baking?

Tags: mesh, export, keyframes, soft-body, mmd-tools

[image: Rendered Image]

[image: Wireframe view]

Hello,  I'm attempting to add this baked simulation to a moving car in another scene. I have it moving exactly how I want it to and now I'm just looking to parent to an object so I can move it to another scene.   I've been trying to come up with the right combination of parenting/shapekeys/workflow in order to bake and export.
I've tried: Baking the keyframes, exporting as mmd, parenting, and constraining but each method has resulted in its unique failures.  Could anyone give me any advice on how to move this simulation?

My Project file is large because of the bake but I've included it in my Dropbox in case anyone can help.

Link to .blend file. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/oxevns8ata8z5vpm8p0jg/Hangin-Balls.blend?rlkey=g9t53vkhuztriitad4ad7l6ln&dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the softbody. It cannot be baked by vanilla Blender.

You can "bake" that to shape keys by using this answer here: [How to bake softbody animation into keyframes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-to-bake-softbody-animation-into-keyframes)

After that you have to delete the softbody and the hook.

The non-softbody objects you can just bake.

After that add an empty and parent all your objects to that empty.

I would recommend moving now all baked objects to one collection.

Then open another blend file -> file -> append (or link) and then choose your collection.